# Polynomial data structure

Tags: c, mathematics

The following is working but I just want to know if I can make it better in any way. 
The header file can be [viewed here](https://github.com/quinnliu/DataStructuresAlgorithmsDesignPatterns/blob/master/src/dataStructures/polynomialInC/Polynomial.h).

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Polynomial.h"

static int64_t power(int64_t x, uint64_t y);

/**
 * Initializes *P as described below.
 *
 * Pre:  P points to an uninitialized Polynomial object,
 *       C != NULL,
 *       C[i] initialized for i = 0:D
 * Post: P->Degree == D,
 *       P->Coeff != C (array is duplicated, not linked),
 *       P->Coeff[i] == C[i] for i = 0:D
 * Returns: false if *P cannot be properly initialized, true otherwise
 */bool Polynomial_Set(Polynomial* const P, const uint8_t D,
        const int64_t* const C) {
    if (P == NULL || C == NULL ) {
        return false;
    }
    P->Degree = D;

    P->Coeff = malloc((D + 1) * sizeof(int64_t));

    // malloc returns NULL if block of memory cannot be allocated
    if (P == NULL ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= P->Degree; i++) {
            P->Coeff[i] = C[i];
        }
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Initializes *Target from *Source as described below.
 *
 * Pre:  Target points to a Polynomial object,
 *       Source points to a properly-initialized Polynomial object
 * Post: Target->Degree == Source->Degree,
 *       Target->Coeff != Source->Coeff,
 *       Target->Coeff[i] == Source->Coeff[i] for i = 0:Source->Degree
 * Returns: false if *Target cannot be properly initialized, true otherwise
 */bool Polynomial_Copy(Polynomial* const Target, const Polynomial* const Source) {
    return Polynomial_Set(Target, Source->Degree, Source->Coeff);
}

/**
 * Compares two polynomials.
 *
 * Pre:  Left points to a properly-initialized Polynomial object,
 *       Right points to a properly-initialized Polynomial object
 * Returns: true if Left and Right have the same coefficients, false otherwise
 */bool Polynomial_Equals(const Polynomial* const Left,
        const Polynomial* const Right) {
    if (Left->Degree != Right->Degree) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= Left->Degree; i++) {
        if (Left->Coeff[i] != Right->Coeff[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // since all coefficients are equal between
    // the two polynomials
}

/**
 * Computes value of polynomial at X.
 *
 * Pre:  P points to a properly-initialized Polynomial object
 * Returns: value of P(X); 0 if cannot be evaluated
 */
int64_t Polynomial_EvaluateAt(const Polynomial* const P, const int64_t X) {
    if (P == NULL ) {
        return 0;
    }
    //TODO: check for overflow, only 2^63 bits can be used to represent the evaluated number
    int64_t result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= P->Degree; i++) {
        int64_t termCoefficient = P->Coeff[i]; // 3
        int64_t termResult = termCoefficient * power(X, i);
        result = result + termResult;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Initializes *Scaled to represent K times *Source
 *
 * Pre:  Scaled points to a Polynomial object,
 *       Source points to a properly-initialized Polynomial object,
 *       Source != Target
 * Post: Scaled->Degree == Source->Degree,
 *       Scaled->Coeff  != Source->Coeff,
 *       Scaled->Coeff[i] == K * Source->Coeff[i] for i = 0:Scaled->Degree
 * Returns: false if *Scaled cannot be properly initialized, true otherwise
 */bool Polynomial_Scale(Polynomial* const Scaled, const Polynomial* const Source,
        const int64_t K) {
    if (Polynomial_Copy(Scaled, Source) == false || Scaled == NULL
            || Source == NULL ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= Scaled->Degree; i++) {
            Scaled->Coeff[i] = K * Scaled->Coeff[i];
        }
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Initializes *Sum to equal *Left + *Right.
 *
 * Pre:  Sum points to a Polynomial object,
 *       Left points to a properly-initialized Polynomial object,
 *       Right points to a properly-initialized Polynomial object,
 *       Sum != Left,
 *       Sum != Right
 * Post: Sum->Degree == max(Left->Degree, Right->Degree),
 *       Sum->Coeff[i] == Left->Coeff[i] + Right->Coeff[i] 
 *           with proper allowance for the case that 
 *           Left->Degree != Right->Degree
 * Returns: false if *Sum cannot be properly initialized, true otherwise
 */bool Polynomial_Add(Polynomial* const Sum, const Polynomial* const Left,
        const Polynomial* const Right) {
    if (Sum == NULL || Left == NULL || Right == NULL ) {
        return false;
    }

    if (Left->Degree > Right->Degree) {
        if (Polynomial_Set(Sum, Left->Degree, Left->Coeff)) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= Right->Degree; i++) {
                Sum->Coeff[i] = Sum->Coeff[i] + Right->Coeff[i];
            }
            Sum->Degree = Left->Degree;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else { // Right polynomial > Left polynomial || Right polynomial == Left polynomial
        if (Polynomial_Set(Sum, Right->Degree, Right->Coeff)) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= Left->Degree; i++) {
                Sum->Coeff[i] = Sum->Coeff[i] + Left->Coeff[i];
            }
            Sum->Degree = Right->Degree;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Consider the case where largest degrees has the same coefficients
    // for Left and Right polynomial and cancel out each other lowering
    // the degree by one. ex. Largest term in each polynomial are
    // 2X^7 and -2X^7 means the Sum will have a degree less than 7.
    // The exact same problem can reoccur for the next polynomial term as 
    // well.

    //  1 + 3X^1 + 3X^2 + 4X^3
    // -1 - 2X^1 - 3X^2 - 4X^3
    int sumDegree = Sum->Degree;
    while(Sum->Coeff[sumDegree] == 0 && sumDegree >= 0) {
        Sum->Degree -= 1;
        sumDegree--;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Initializes *Diff to equal *Left - *Right.
 *
 * Pre:  Diff points to a Polynomial object,
 *       Left points to a properly-initialized Polynomial object,
 *       Right points to a properly-initialized Polynomial object,
 *       Diff != Left,
 *       Diff != Right
 * Post: Diff->Degree is set correctly,
 *       Diff->Coeff[i] == Left->Coeff[i] - Right->Coeff[i] 
 *           with proper allowance for the case that 
 *           Left->Degree != Right->Degree
 * Returns: false if *Diff cannot be properly initialized, true otherwise
 */bool Polynomial_Subtract(Polynomial* const Diff, const Polynomial* const Left,
        const Polynomial* const Right) {
    if (Diff == NULL || Left == NULL || Right == NULL ) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= Right->Degree; i++) {
        Right->Coeff[i] = -Right->Coeff[i];
    }
    return Polynomial_Add(Diff, Left, Right);
}

/**
 * Computes the first derivative of Source.
 *
 * Pre:  Target points to a Polynomial object,
 *       Source points to a properly-initialized Polynomial object,
 *       Target != Source
 * Post: Target->Degree is set correctly
 *       Target->Coeff[i] == iith coefficient of Source'
 *
 * Returns: false if Source' cannot be properly initialized, true otherwise
 */bool Polynomial_Differentiate(Polynomial* const Target,
        const Polynomial* const Source) {
    if (Target == NULL || Source == NULL ) {
        return false;
    }
    // EXAMPLE:
    //Source->Coeff    0         1          2        3
    //               1X^0 +   2X^1 +     3X^2 +   4X^3
    //       0   + 2*1X^0 +   2*3X^1 + 3*4X^2

    //free(Target->Coeff);
    if (Source->Degree == 0) {
        Polynomial_Zero(Source);
        Polynomial_Copy(Target, Source);
        return true;
    }

    Target->Degree = Source->Degree - 1;
    // add 1 to Target->Degree because one additional space is need to
    // hold a int64_t at Target->Coeff[0]
    Target->Coeff = malloc((Target->Degree + 1) * sizeof(int64_t));
    for (int degree = 1; degree <= Source->Degree; degree++) {
        //Target->Coeff[0]      =   1    *           2          = 2
        //Target->Coeff[1]      =   2    *           3          = 6
        //Target->Coeff[2]      =   3    *           4          = 12
        Target->Coeff[degree-1] = degree * Source->Coeff[degree];
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Reset P to represent zero polynomial.
 *
 * Pre:  P points to a Polynomial object
 * Post: P->Degree == 0
 *       P->Coeff is set appropriately
 */bool Polynomial_Zero(Polynomial* const P) {
    if (P == NULL ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        free(P->Coeff);
        P->Degree = 0;

        P->Coeff = malloc((P->Degree + 1) * sizeof(int64_t));
        P->Coeff[0] = 0;

        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * power function that calculated x raised to the
 * power y in O(log N).
 */
static int64_t power(int64_t x, uint64_t y) {
    int temp;
    if (y == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    temp = power(x, y / 2);
    if (y % 2 == 0) {
        return temp * temp;
    } else {
        return x * temp * temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Polynomial_EvaluateAt` returns 0 if `P` is `NULL`. But I guess the function could also return 0 as part of a "normal" result (X == 0 for example). Not sure if it's important to distinguish between those two. You could consider returning a `bool` and pass the result through a pass-by-ref argument. This would be slightly more consistent with your other functions which basically do the same.